# how to select an anchor tag with an specific id

Tags: reference, tags, anchor

I want to add an class to an specific anchor tag

what i am doing is this....

```
$('#footerMenu > a#40').addClass['currentLink'];
```

the tag itself is

```
<a pageid="40" id="40" class="getPage" href="#Home">Home</a>
```

please some insight..

regards,

wouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an `id` is meant to be unique, you can just use

```
$('#40').addClass('currentLink');
```

If you have any doubt on the usage of IDs, check the chapter “Guidelines for efficient CSS“ on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS) !